# 2D Rigid Scan Matcher for Sparse Points (<=3) for Global Localization

Tags: ros2, odometry, localization, rangefinder, pointclouds

I am working on a wheeled robot in ROS2 Humble that navigates in the XY plane. The robot currently uses wheeled odometry for position estimation, but due to its dead reckoning nature it experiences drift issues. To correct these errors, I plan to stop the robot at known locations, such as corners of the room, and use range sensors located on bot to correct these errors. Due to financial constraints I am unable to get LIDARs etc, and have only distance sensor on hand. To achieve the correction, I am looking at using point cloud registration methods on the following 2 clouds:

- Data from 2-3 single range sensors, which are placed in the co-ordinate frame  of map using odometry data. This will contain as many points as the amount of range sensors
- Map of room, which for all intents and purposes can be considered static. This will contain as many points as we can deem.

I am intending to use this as a substitute for other global localisation algorithms. The following can be assumed depending upon if 2 or 3 range sensors are being used.

- For 2 Range Sensors, the rotational error can be assumed to be zero, and only relative x,y error needs to be found.
- For 3 Range Sensors, x,y,theta transforms would be ideal. If not, then more robust x,y data will also work.

Are there any predefined methods or existing implementations in ROS2 that I can use or potentially use in my system? Or any implementation in ROS1 that I can port? I have looked into ICP (Iterative Closest Point) but am not entirely convinced as I haven't personally used it before

Your insights and recommendations will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!